# How do I install Ubuntu 14.10 32-bit desktop using the Khmer language?

Tags: system-installation, language-support

I am doing a thesis about Ubuntu 14.10 with the Khmer language, but when I install it I can't find Khmer language (`ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso`). But when I install Ubuntu 14.10 Server, it has Khmer for my language choice (`ubuntu-14.10-server-amd64.iso`).

---

Yes sure, i want to display Khmer language while installing and display Khmer Language on my desktop.
But this is my first time with Ubuntu so i don't know much about it.

Thank You !

Comment: Are you talking about display language or input language?

Comment: Btw, did you look for "Central Khmer"?

Comment: Yes sure, i want to display Khmer language while installing and display Khmer Language on my desktop. But this is my first time with Ubuntu so i don't know much about it.

Thank You !

Comment: Ok.. AFAIK it should be available also on the desktop ISO. If it's not, you can easily switch to Khmer after the installation by using [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html).

Comment: @Gunnar please add that information as an answer. Hopefully with some details :)

Comment: @Anwar: Why? That kind of basic question is covered in the official documentation, whose maintenance I've been working with for several cycles. That's why I simply linked to it.

Comment: I think it's no longer supported (regardless of the language you are looking for) so you might want to look for something more recent like 17.04 or 16.04 / 14.04 if you want the LTS.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson because if you believe that is the answer, then it should be in answer section, not in comment. Because AskUbuntu's primary job is to be a question/answer site. Even when there are documentations for a problem, if it is asked here, we'll answer _here_. It also helps get the site cleaner from dangling questions like these. But, if you think your comment isn't an answer fully, then I'd agree with you.

Comment: @Anwar: The problem description was never confirmed, the OP is gone since long, and I don't consider my comment to fit in the answer section.